# Absolute Path of project file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to print the absolute path of the file `rep.xml` in **eclipse plug-in**.

I have placed the file `rep.xml` under the path
`C:\Program Files\Eclipse\Documents\Eclipse\samplePlugin\resources\rep.xml.`

I tried printing it using `file.getLocation()`.
It returns `C:/Program Files/eclipse/Documents/runtime-EclipseApplication`

How do I print the absolute path in eclipse. Please help.

Comment: That is the absolute path. That file is in your run time workspace and is not related to the file in your development workspace.

Comment: Note: If you want to read a file from your plugin you don't use `IFile`, there is a separate API for reading plugin files.

Comment: It is just a normal xml file. How to get the path of that file during plug-in runtime? Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to read a file that is part of your plugin use this:

```
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("your plugin id");

URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("path relative to the plugin"), null);

URL fileUrl = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);

File file = new File(fileUrl.getFile());

... read file using normal Java file APIs
```

You can also use `FrameworkUtil` to get the bundle which avoids having to hard code the plugin id:

```
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());
```

gives you the `Bundle` containing the given class.

Comment: @greg-449..Really thanks a lot for the code. It worked without any errors.Cheers!!!